# Anybody know what this error means? will be fat and ar(1) will not be able to operate on it

Tags: ios, xcode, rubymotion

I'm compiling my app (it's a Rubymotion app) with SSPullToRefresh and keep getting this message:

```
will be fat and ar(1) will not be able to operate on it
```

Anybody know what it means and how I should deal with it?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but see the source code for [libtool/ranlib](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-435/misc/libtool.c) and the `-f` option in the [ranlib man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ranlib/). It's a universal app related warning.

Comment: I have the same error when running `rake device` ... in the simulator works fine

Comment: I've just opened an issue https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotion/issues/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem has been fixed.

https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotion/issues/41